# TableView not showing right stuff

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

So i have a Person class:

```
package tableview;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Person {

private SimpleStringProperty name;

private SimpleBooleanProperty smart;

public Person(String name, boolean smart) {
    this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
    this.smart = new SimpleBooleanProperty(smart);
}

public SimpleStringProperty getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(SimpleStringProperty name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public SimpleBooleanProperty getSmart() {
    return smart;
}
}
```

and this is how i add them to the ObservableList of Persons

```
        person.add(new Person("Emre", false));
```

and this is how i set the CellValueFactory

```
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("name"));
```

and these are the columns

```
@FXML
public TableColumn<Person, String> nameColumn;

@FXML
public TableColumn<Person, Boolean> smartColumn;
```

But it shows this on the table view

[image: screenshot of result]

is there anyway to show the string for the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public String getName() {
    return name.get();
}

    public boolean getSmart() {
    return smart.get();
}
```